# .htaccess mod_rewrite and Google indexing

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, google-index

I need help on `.htaccess mod_rewrite`  and Google indexing...
I've got a site and wrote in `.htaccess` in arch subdomain the following code:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^arch.startingdomain.it
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://finaldomain.it/$1 [P]
```

In this way I have a redirect from `arch.startingdomain.it` to `finaldomain.it` viewing old urls visible on the address bar in the browser.
So this is the question:

Will Google index the urls as `arch.startingdomain.it/index.asp?id=1` or `finaldomain.it`?

Comment: Google will only index `arch.startingdomain.it/index.asp?id=1` since it won't know about proxy to `finaldomain.it`